# Cannot Close Angular Material Cdkoverlay From BackdropClick

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I'm currently using the `Angular Material cdkoverlay` and want to close it when I click anywhere else on the screen except for the overlay.  I've gone aheadand subscribed to `backdropClick()` but I can't get it to fire.

```
launchOverlay() {
        let strategy = this.overlay.position()
        .connectedTo(
            this._overlayOrigin,
            {originX: 'end', originY: 'top'},
            {overlayX: 'end', overlayY: 'top'} );
        let config = new OverlayConfig({positionStrategy: strategy, width: '280px', scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition()});
        this._overlayRef = this.overlay.create(config);
        this._overlayRef.attach(new TemplatePortal(this.filterTemplate, this.viewContainerRef));
        this._overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => this.close()}, () => console.log("ERROR"), () => console.log("COMPLETE"));
}

 close(){
    this._overlayRef.dispose();
}

<ng-template cdkPortal #columnFilter>
    <mat-card>
        HELLO WORLD
    </mat-card>
</ng-template>
```

Everything with creating and launching the overlay works fine, it's just responding to the outside click.

If I add `hasBackdrop: true` to `OverlayConfig` then it creates the dark grey backdrop and the click outside works, but I don't want a visiable backdrop, like the selete component.

Comment: I upvoted just because of this line in your code :)                                                                    this._overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => this.close()}

Comment: Does COMPLETE ever get printed out ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
hasBackdrop: true,
backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop'
```

Adds the transparent backdrop inwhich the select and other components use.

Comment: what if i am using it with the help of directives in that case i have no reference of overlay

Answer (score 11):

In case if someone is using template and directives then you can use `cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop` and `cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass` directives.

And for transparent backdrop use the css class `cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop`

```
<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger" [cdkConnectedOverlayHasBackdrop]="true"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayBackdropClass]="'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop'" [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isDropdownOpen"
    (backdropClick)="toggleDropdown()">
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that doesn't want/need a backdrop, you can use the *overlayOutsideClick* event emitter documented in https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#CdkConnectedOverlay :

```
<ng-template>
  cdkConnectedOverlay 
  (overlayOutsideClick)="close()"
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways but I'll tell you two of them when you want to handle it with code, not on HTML.

**1. Dispose of the Overlay on the Backdrop Click**

> this.overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => {
> this.overlayRef.dispose();});

**2. Dispose of the Overlay on Outside Pointer Event**

With this one, you don't need to keep the backdrop and with this out of overlay would be clickable to take some actions. It's up to you. It works with a backdrop too.

> ```
> this.overlayRef.detachBackdrop(); //detach backdrop to make clickable out of the overlay
> //Event Listener Observable to dispose itself:
> this.overlayRef.outsidePointerEvents().subscribe(() => {
>       //maybe some actions that you could take  
>     this.overlayRef.dispose();
>     });
> ```